# NPM package output message at the very end

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Did anyone know if it's possible to print a log message at the very end after the **npm install**?

```
  To enable CLI tab autocompletion run:
   mypackage completion >> ~/.profile


  progress@1.1.8 node_modules/progress

  kew@0.6.0 node_modules/kew

  adm-zip@0.4.7 node_modules/adm-zip

  request-progress@0.3.1 node_modules/request-progress
  └── throttleit@0.0.2
  ....
```

But I want to give a message after the dependency download, e.g:

```
  progress@1.1.8 node_modules/progress

  kew@0.6.0 node_modules/kew

  adm-zip@0.4.7 node_modules/adm-zip

  request-progress@0.3.1 node_modules/request-progress
  └── throttleit@0.0.2
  To enable CLI tab autocompletion run:
   mypackage completion >> ~/.profile
```

I tried it via a post installation script, but doesn't work

Comment: Can you post your attempts?

Answer (score 8):

From the [npm documentation on `"scripts"`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) it states you can use the `"postinstall"` (or just `"install"`) linked up with a command to run after the package has installed...

Since you say you already attempted this, but gave no context in your question on how, let me just walk you through the process...

For example, say this were in your `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node postinstall.js"
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, in your project directory, you can create a `postintall.js` script, and put this in it:

```
console.log(
  "To enable CLI tab autocompletion run:\n" + 
  "mypackage completion >> ~/.profile"
);
```

Comment: Also, I've noticed that you've never accepted an answer before...  If this solved your problem, click the checkmark.  You and I both will receive reputation points.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to print a message at the very end.

Answer (score 3):

I also run into this problem. My workaround was to use custom script:

```
"scripts": {
  "presetup": "npm install -g",
  "setup": "node postinstall.js"
},
```

(I need my tool to be installed globally, hance `-g`. This, of course, can be omitted.)

And then I asked my users to run this line, instead of the usual *npm install*:

> npm run-script setup my-package.tgz

Note that *npm install* still works. It just won't show the final message.