# How to define a custom console.log if a script in package.json throws an error?

Tags: json, npm, package.json

Is it possible to add a custom console.log if my custom npm script throws an error? Or is it at all possible to add custom console.log to a script?

I have this entry in my scripts object of **package.json**:

```
"check": "npm list --depth=0 | grep"
```

And need a console.log specifically for this script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM package output message at the very end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875343/npm-package-output-message-at-the-very-end)